# Write a function inside jquery .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running a bg slider..."Supersized - Fullscreen Slideshow jQuery Plugin"

what i need is when a background changes some contents in a specific div must also change...

here i found a code line from script

```
if (options.slide_captions) 
   $('#slidecaption').html(options.slides[currentSlide].title);
```

this one pulls the image title to a specific div, but i want to load unique div for each background change...

or is there any other ways to do??

i have very little knowledge in jquery...
please help

advance thanks...

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle for this? It will be easier for us to understand.

Answer (score 0):

you can write this:

```
if (options.slide_captions) $('#slidecaption').html(options.slides[currentSlide].title, function(){
//write the code that load the unique div

});
```

tell me if it works

Comment: I don't think this works. Check here http://jsfiddle.net/VnnZB/. `.html()` takes only one parameter which htmlString (or function returning htmlString) Check jQuery Docs.

Comment: Thanks for your comments..  this works for me..                                          $('#slidecaption').html(function(){

var bgtitle=options.slides[currentSlide].title;

if (bgtitle=='slide1'){
 var divcontent='Html content for div 1';
}else if(bgtitle=='slide2'){
 var divcontent='Html content for div 2';
}

$('#slidecaption').html('<div class="'+bgtitle+'" style="display:inline;">'+divcontent+'</div>');

});

Answer (score 0):

http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/docs.html#theme-after

Check-out the `theme.afterAnimation( )` documentation. You can set it to a function that changes the content after the slide changes.